# Richtextbox : Find multi line string in multi line text

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have a RichTextBox in which I am displaying a paragraph and I need to change the color of multiple line of text.

I tried using the `RichTextBox.Find` method but it only works for a single line.
Here is my code:

```
richTextBox1.Text=@"Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
"
Font fnt = new Font("Verdana", 8F, FontStyle.Italic, GraphicsUnit.Point);
string mystring = @"Line 2
Line 3";
//string mystring = @"Line 2";
if (richTextBox1.Find(mystring)>0)
{
    int my1stPosition = richTextBox1.Find(mystring);
    richTextBox1.SelectionStart=my1stPosition;
    richTextBox1.SelectionLength=mystring.Length;
    richTextBox1.SelectionFont=fnt;
    richTextBox1.SelectionColor=Color.CadetBlue;
}
```

So when I search for just `"Line 2"` it works but it doesn't work for:

```
"Line 2  
Line 3"
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: Are you sure the kind of line endings the rtb has, and the line endings your search string has, are the same? (CRLF vs LF etc). What about markup? Are there any invisible rtf formatting markers in the rtb that your search string doesn’t have?

Comment: I tried using richTextBox1.Text=mystring, in which case both textbox and find will have same value, it still didn't work

Comment: Really only you can solve this unless you can reliably give us the data etc.. maybe convert your search string to bytes (encoding.ascii.getbytes) and the rtb text to bytes, and eyeball the differences.. there will be something

Comment: Re your “I set the text to mystring” - yes but maybe that means the text is found at position 0, and your if only considers things found if they are at index greater than 0. Try >=0 ?

Comment: Side note on your code, you find and then find again.. why not capture the int index the first time you do a find? `int idx = find...; if(idx >=0) ...`

Comment: tried >=0 still not working, I have created a simple proj and uploaded it to one drive
https://1drv.ms/f/s!AlyBhK9gzDw2khz0oPhGe9rU_XnZ
please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [RichTextBox.Find()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.find?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_RichTextBox_Find_System_String_) method cannot search in multiple lines of the `Text`.
If your intention is to search for and select the content of different lines, then you can split the lines in different substrings. This way, you'll be able to select multiple lines even if they're not contiguous:

**Note**:
`RichTextBox` converts `\r\n` (`Environment.Newline` in Windows) to `\n`.

For example:

```
richTextBox1.Text = "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3\nLine 4\nLine 5";
string[] searchLines = new[] {"Line 2", "Line 3"};

using (Font fnt = new Font("Verdana", 8F, FontStyle.Italic, GraphicsUnit.Point))
{
    foreach (string line in searchLines)
    {
        int my1stPosition = richTextBox1.Find(line);
        if (my1stPosition > 0)
        {
            richTextBox1.SelectionStart = my1stPosition;
            richTextBox1.SelectionLength = line.Length;
            richTextBox1.SelectionFont = fnt;
            richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.CadetBlue;
        }
    }
}
```

If you still want to search for a whole string, then use **`IndexOf`** on the **`RichTextBox.Text`** property:

```
string searchLines = $"Line 2\nLine 3";

(...)
int my1stPosition = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(searchLines);
```

Comment: great idea that worked. small improvement since my search string is not constant i did this instead 
string[] searchLines =  mystring.Split(new [] { Environment.NewLine }, 
                               StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

Comment: Ok. See the note, it could be a time saver (in some cases).

Comment: even second option worked but length seems to have some issue, its counting line characters and changing color for few extra characters than needed

Comment: Use `\n` as separator, not `\r\n` (as in the note), otherwise the string length won't match the actual text length.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I missing something?

I missed it too, first look

[The fine manual says:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.find?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Note
>   The Find methods that accept a string as a parameter cannot find text that is contained on more than one line of text within the RichTextBox. Performing such a search will return a value of negative one (-1).